# Setting cookies on a per page basis in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work:

```
    if (isset($_COOKIE['thisPageRated'])) {
        die();
    } else {
        $pageCookieSet = substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/'))); //use wordpress function to get the current page and then we slice off the domain
        $expire = time()+3600; //expires in a hour
        $value = 'set'; //value i'm giving the cookie
        $name = 'thisPageRated'; //name of the cookie
        setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $pageCookieSet);
        //do some stuff
    }
```

I want to set a cookie on a per page basis as i'm trying to stop people rating a page more then once. But it seems to set it for the entire site for some reason. the path is coming out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First adding a new cookie every page isn't a good idea in my opinion since nobody likes to be overflow with cookies.

Second, what you could do is create a single cookie with a list of page views with a separator, for example :

Your user have rated the page with the IDs 5 , 7 and 11.

```
    $pageCookieSet = substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/'))); //use wordpress         function to get the current page and then we slice off the domain
    $expire = time()+3600; //expires in a hour
    $value = '5'; //value i'm giving the cookie
    $name = 'PagesRated'; //name of the cookie
    setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $pageCookieSet);
```

So here we just created to note that the page 5 has been rated.

After that you just have to update the value of this cookie.

```
$_COOKIE['pagesRated'] = $_COOKIE['pagesRated'].'###'.$otherPageValue;
```

$otherPageValue being here the ID of the second page

Here we've updated our cookie so it'll now return :

5###7

After that you just have to parse the value of your cookie using the separator ###

```
$arrayPagesRated = explode('###',$_COOKIE['pagesRated');
```

This line will create an array with the IDs of all pages rated like this :

```
  $arrayPagesRated[0] = 5; 
  $arrayPagesRated[1] = 7;
```

And now a quick in_array with your page to check which pages have already been rated and that would do the trick

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, this sounds like a good solution, little confused by the '$otherPageValue' variable. What is this exactly? So the second snippet needs to go directly after setting the cookie? The third line puts the cookie values into a variable so then I can just do if (in_array($arrayPagesRated)) then blah blah?

Comment: thanks for clarifying, but still not to sure about this other value, would this not be in the cookie itself? How would I get it?

Comment: $_COOKIE['pagesRated'], will return the value of the cookie which is at first 5, the ID of the first page then we append the other page to the value of this cookie with a separator. (Sorry I dont really understand where is your question ^^')

Comment: Hi, confused where 7 is coming from if it's already been set? I thought in the example that should already be in the array?

Comment: Well I named your pages using ID :
5 = First Page
7 = Second Page

So I just add the name of the second page after the first one, but I dont know how you're planning to see the difference between two pages